# CSS/HTML фреймворк для обычных страниц

Tags: html, css, framework, wysiwyg, контент

Нужен CSS/HTML фреймворк для обычного контента. Существует ли вообще что-то подобное? Как называются такие фреймворки? Постараюсь объяснить, что я имею в виду.

Есть сайт (абстрактный), у которого уже сверстан основной шаблон - шапка, футер, главная с каруселями и слайдерами, все это.

Осталось дать инструмент для контент-менеджера, с помощью которого он в админке сможет заполнять содержимое обычных текстовых страниц. Но так, чтобы это выглядело привлекательно.

Задача абсолютно стандартная.

Обычно контент-менеджер в WYSIWYG-редакторе в админке пишет текст, списки, вставляет таблички. Иногда ему нужно вставить что-то вроде цитаты или параграфа с иллюстрацией в виде картинки. И появляются блоки с фиксированной шириной, картинки float'ами. Что, во-первых, выглядит не очень, а во-вторых, плохо сочетается с адаптивностью.

Я бы хотел, чтобы контент-менеджер не занимался ручной раскраской текста и установкой ширины блоков, а использовал "конструктор" из готовых элементов.

И вот нужен фреймворк/конструктор, который такие элементы предоставляет. Что там условно должно быть:

- Поддержка адаптивности.
- Вертикальный ритм.
- Заголовки, параграфы, списки, таблички и т. п.
- И различные виджеты, которые позволяют украсить страницу, например:

  - Выделенный параграф (блок текста, привлекающий внимание).
  - **Текст с картинкой.** Здесь возможно, несколько виджетов на выбор, потому что это может быть короткий текст с картинкой или длинный текст с картинкой - их вид и адаптивное поведение может различаться.
  - Мини-галерея фотографий.
  - Figure (видео или картинка).
  - И т. п.

И имея такие инструменты, контент-менеджер собирает страничку из готовых кусочков, просто заполняя текст и вставляя картинки в заранее заготовленные места. Не понравилось, как выглядит контент в одном виджете - взял другой.

Как результат - это выглядит красиво и согласованно.

Важно, чтобы это был именно целостный фреймворк, в котором все компоненты согласованы. Как собрать такой "конструктор" из компонентов из интернета, и так понятно. Нужен именно единый подход и общая логика.

Для верстальщика должна оставаться возможность накладывать тему (цветовое решение, шрифт, базовый размер шрифта, регулировать вертикальный ритм и пр.).

Я не знаю, как это называется. Фреймворки, которые я видел/использовал, предлагают сетку, формы, кнопки, табы и прочее, но это все не нужно для обычного контента. А вот фреймворка, который решал бы такую простую задачу как "разместить картинку с текстом", не обременяя тебя понятием float и нюансами его поведения, я пока не нашел.

Существует ли что-либо подобное и если да, то как это называется?